# Verification by Linkedin platform team needed

Tags: linkedin-api

- Created an app/product to do a social login using Linkedin for website [www.lifeschool10.nl](http://www.lifeschool10.nl).
- The app/product was verified by the business owner of the company lifeschool10.
- However there is also verification needed by the LinkedIn platform team .... see the attachment.
- It states that this will be done in 3-5 days but sofar this has not been done.
- Can you please update me with a status or inform me what else/additional I have to do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG2Gl.jpg)

Regards Walter.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't the LinkedIn support system.

Comment: I had first opened a ticket in the LinkedIn support system but was then adviced by LinkedIn support to post my  question on StackOverflow even after I mentioned that it is not a technica/developperl question but a question why my app/product verification by the LinkedIn platform team is not done.